# When you go out of the room, please close the door

Tags: prepositions

When you go out of the room, please close the door.----Is it correct?

Comment: "When you leave, please close the door on your way out. Thank you."

Comment: It may or may not be "correct". Please use the **[edit]** link to add more details to your question. If you don't, your question may be closed, and we would like to help. Our [**Details, Please**](https://meta.ell.stackexchange.com/questions/439/please-everyone-details-please) meta post will help you understand.

Answer (score 1):

It's OK, but better ways to say it are:

> When you leave the room, please close the door.
>
> Please close the door when you leave the room.